# Keras layer for slicing image data into sliding windows

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, sliding-window

I have a set of images, all of varying widths, but with fixed height set to 100 pixels and 3 channels of depth. My task is to classify if each vertical line in the image is interesting or not. To do that, I look at the line in context of its 10 predecessor and successor lines. Imagine the algorithm sweeping from left to right of the image, detecting  vertical lines containing points of interest.

My first attempt at doing this was to manually cut out these sliding windows using numpy before feeding the data into the Keras model. Like this:

```
# Pad left and right
s = np.repeat(D[:1], 10, axis = 0)
e = np.repeat(D[-1:], 10, axis = 0)
# D now has shape (w + 20, 100, 3)
D = np.concatenate((s, D, e))
# Sliding windows creation trick from SO question
idx = np.arange(21)[None,:] + np.arange(len(D) - 20)[:,None]
windows = D[indexer]
```

Then all windows and all ground truth 0/1 values for all vertical lines in all images would be concatenated into two very long arrays.

I have verified that this works, in principle. I fed each window to a Keras layer looking like this:

```
Conv2D(20, (5, 5), input_shape = (21, 100, 3), padding = 'valid', ...)
```

But the windowing causes the memory usage to increase 21 times so doing it this way becomes impractical. But I think my scenario is a very common in machine learning so there must be some standard method in Keras to do this efficiently? E.g I would like to feed Keras my raw image data (w, 100, 80) and tell it what the sliding window sizes are and let it figure out the rest. I have looked at some sample code but I'm a ml noob so I don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't an easy problem because it can involve using a variable sized input for your Keras model. While I think it is possible to do this with proper use of placeholders that's certainly no place for a beginner to start. your other option is a data generator. As with many computationally intensive tasks there is often a trade off between compute speed and memory requirements, using a generator is more compute heavy and it will be done entirely on your cpu (no gpu acceleration), but it won't make the memory increase.

The point of a data generator is that it will apply the operation to images one at a time to produce the batch, then train on that batch, then free up the memory - so you only end up keeping one batch worth of data in memory at any time. Unfortunately if you have a time consuming generation then this can seriously affect performance.

The generator will be a python generator (using the 'yield' keyword) and is expected to produce a single batch of data, keras is very good at using arbitrary batch sizes, so you can always make one image yield one batch, especially to start.

Here is the keras page on fit_generator - I warn you, this starts to become a lot of work very quickly, consider buying more memory: 
https://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator

Fine I'll do it for you :P

```py
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import keras
    from keras.models import Model, model_from_json
    from keras.layers import Dense, Concatenate, Multiply,Add, Subtract, Input, Dropout, Lambda, Conv1D, Flatten
    from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
    # check for my gpu 
    print(device_lib.list_local_devices())


    # make some fake image data

    # 1000 random widths
    data_widths = np.floor(np.random.random(1000)*100)

    # producing 1000 random images with dimensions w x 100 x 3
    # and a vector of which vertical lines are interesting
    # I assume your data looks like this
    images = []
    interesting = []
    for w in data_widths:
        images.append(np.random.random([int(w),100,3]))
        interesting.append(np.random.random(int(w))>0.5)

    # this is a generator
    def image_generator(images, interesting):
        num = 0
        while num < len(images):
            windows = None
            truth = None

            D = images[num]
            # this should look familiar

            # Pad left and right
            s = np.repeat(D[:1], 10, axis = 0)
            e = np.repeat(D[-1:], 10, axis = 0)
            # D now has shape (w + 20, 100, 3)
            D = np.concatenate((s, D, e))
            # Sliding windows creation trick from SO question
            idx = np.arange(21)[None,:] + np.arange(len(D) - 20)[:,None]
            windows = D[idx]
            truth = np.expand_dims(1*interesting[num],axis=1)
            yield (windows, truth)
            num+=1
            # the generator MUST loop
            if num == len(images):
                num = 0

    # basic model - replace with your own
    input_layer = Input(shape = (21,100,3), name = "input_node")
    fc = Flatten()(input_layer)
    fc = Dense(100, activation='relu',name = "fc1")(fc)
    fc = Dense(50, activation='relu',name = "fc2")(fc)
    fc = Dense(10, activation='relu',name = "fc3")(fc)
    output_layer = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name = "output")(fc)

    model = Model(input_layer,output_layer)
    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='binary_crossentropy')
    model.summary()

    #and training
    training_history = model.fit_generator(image_generator(images, interesting),
                        epochs =5,
                        initial_epoch = 0,
                        steps_per_epoch=len(images),
                        verbose=1
                       )
```

Comment: Can you show me how to do it? I still think my use case must be very common. :)

Comment: If you want you can even load the images in the generator, to free up even more memory. But I'll leave that one for you

Comment: the "a lot of work" I was talking about comes in when you try to use threading or multiprocessing to free up even more memory and squeeze additional performance out of your machine - this example actually turned out to be pretty easy